# Switching between different activities inside a Tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I have a tab layout, inside which I am successfully able to lead an Activity.

However, I would want such a mechanism so that I can have few buttons in the bottom, and when the user clicks them, I am able to load different Activities inside the same Tab.

This functionality may closely resemble having Tabs inside a Tab, which, I feel, isn't a good practice and will make the things quite unpredictable.

how to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be achieved by using Activity Groups.........

Search for some samples........

I am providing two links, check if it helps you............

[Link1](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

[Link2](http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/#comment-7)

Comment: Thanks viv. I'll try that out and will let you know.